# How to copy the value in a lookup field to a related item in the same lookup column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, lookup-column

I'm looking to fill out a lookup column. I have a couple of Sharepoint Designer Workflows to set a lookup column field in list A to a related ID from another list B when an item is created in list C. It works fine, but only the first related item gets set, in order of ID. I need help in making a Workflow that sets the lookup field for all the items in list A.

So if an item gets created in another list, it sets this lookup column to a certain value. I need this value applied to all related items in the same list, not just the first.

[image],